# Copy data from one sheet and paste to another (under some conditions)

Tags: excel, vba

My macro copies data from several sheets (the particular one is called SS) and pastes it to another one (MainSheet):

```
Dim lastrow As Long
'(...)

Lastrowss = Sheets (“SS”).Range(“A1”).End(xlDown).Row
'(...)

For i = 2 To lastrows
'    (...)

    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 7).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 7).Value 'Rec Amount
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 9).Value * -1  'Paid Amount
```

The macro works only for the **sells**. **Buys** are reflected in the opposite way.

The macro should copy the data from column 7 and 9 and paste it to columns 9 and 7 (not 7 and 9) only if there is "buy" in column D. If there is a "sell" the data should remain the same.

In column D you do not always get just “sell” or “buy”. You could also see “sell to cover” etc. But the logic remains the same.

Comment: I worry about the fact that you declare a variable called `lastrow`, then assign a value to a different variable called `Lastrowss`, then use yet another variable called `lastrows` for your loop.  Please add `Option Explicit` to the start of each code module.

Comment: That was my typo. Should have been: For i = 2 To lastrowss

Comment: I still worry that you declare a variable called `lastrow` and then use a variable called `lastrowss`.  Add `Option Explicit` at the start of each code module and you can avoid this type of typo.

Comment: Sure, now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 4).Value <> "buy" Then ' <-- add this test
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 7).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 7).Value 'Rec Amount
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 9).Value * -1  'Paid Amount
Else ' <-- here we inverse the two columns
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 7).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 9).Value 'Rec Amount
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 7).Value * -1  'Paid Amount

End If
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. Unfortunately it's not working. I get the Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help.
I have slightly updated the code:

```
If Left(Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 4).Value, 3) <> "Buy" Then
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 7).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 7).Value 'Rec Amount
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 9).Value * -1  'Paid Amount
Else
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 7).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 9).Value 'Rec Amount
    Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("SS").Cells(i, 7).Value * -1  'Paid Amount

End If
```

Seems to work now.

Comment: Since your answer was based heavily upon @A.S.H 's answer, perhaps accepting his answer would be fair to his efforts.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why does your code not give a "type mismatch" when A.S.H's code did?  (All I can think of is some of your "amounts" aren't actually amounts.)

Comment: Done @Scott Holtzman. I am not very familiar with rules on this forum.